# ORM model change causes errors like "column … does not exist"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Have been trying to figure this out for an hour - and still have no idea what the problem is.

The following code is causing the error:

```
team = Team.query.filter_by(name=request.form['newTeamName']).first()
```

More details on the error:

> ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column team.user_id does not
> exist

What should I do to fix this bug?

Comment: Does your Team table *have* an actual column named `user_id`?

Comment: I just checked a couple of seconds ago and the table in PGAdmin3 doesn't have a user_id. How do I add it to the table? Sorry, this is my first time building a web app so I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you've modified the model without updating the database. You need to do this via a migration of some sort. For things like adding new tables you can simply run `metadata.create_all(bind=engine)`. However for fine-grained changes like adding columns, etc, you need to alter the table yourself or use a system like alembic. Of course if this is just during development you should probably just blow away the database and recreate it with the new definitions.

Comment: This is during development luckily, how do I blow away the database and recreate it with the new definitions?

Comment: 'blowing away' isn't something sqlalchemy helps you with too much.  Once' you've done that with the local equivalent of "drop database foo; create database foo;' , the `create_all` snippet in this answer will do.

Comment: you can blow it away pretty quickly using drop_all(), that's what I usually do.  if the database has table defs that don't match the model, you can use the [drop everything recipe](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/DropEverything), but make sure you don't need any of the tables in that schema...